# debugging in python

Tags: python

i am using the python shell to try to do debugging

i set a breakpoint

i did:

```
>>> import pdb
>>> import mymodule
>>> pdb.run('mymodule.test()')
```

but it is just running my program without stopping at the breakpoint!

what am i donig wrong?

Comment: For python version below 3.7 use import pdb;pdb.set_trace() and for above python 3.7 version use breakpoint()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting started with the Python debugger, pdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228637/getting-started-with-the-python-debugger-pdb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you set a breakpoint?  Try adding the line in your code:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

and then run it.  If you're in the pdb shell, then "break foo.py:45" will break on line 45 of file foo.py.

Here are some useful commands:

```
h    help, list commands
s    step through current line
n    step to next line
u    go up the stack
c    continue execution
```

Check the full list by typing 'h'.  And "help X" will give you help on command X.   Also, see this tutorial:

- [Interactive Debugging in Python](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2005/09/01/debugger.html)

Answer (score 2):

The [typical usage](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) to break into the debugger from a running program is to insert

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

at the location you want to break into the debugger. You can then step through the code following this statement, and continue running without the debugger using the c command.

The [typical usage](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) to inspect a crashed program is:

```
>>> import pdb
>>> import mymodule
>>> mymodule.test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "./mymodule.py", line 4, in test
    test2()
  File "./mymodule.py", line 3, in test2
    print spam
NameError: spam
>>> pdb.pm()
> ./mymodule.py(3)test2()
-> print spam
(Pdb)
```

The Python site offers a very elaborate tutorial for `pdb`. Go to http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html.