# Getting started with the Python debugger, pdb

Tags: python, pdb

I want to add [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)—the Python debugger—to my toolbox. What's the best way to get started?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Here's a list of resources to get started with the Python debugger:

1. Read Steve Ferb's article ["Debugging in Python"](https://web.archive.org/web/20110718104449/http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/)
2. Watch Eric Holscher's screencast ["Using pdb, the Python Debugger"](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/aug/30/using-pdb-python-debugger-django-debugging-series-/)
3. Read the [Python documentation for pdb — The Python Debugger](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html)
4. Read Chapter 9—When You Don't Even Know What to Log: Using Debuggers—of Karen Tracey's [*Django 1.1 Testing and Debugging*](https://www.packtpub.com/django-1-1-testing-and-debugging/book).

Comment: Eric Holscher has quite a bit on debugging: [1](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/aug/28/screencast-debugging-django-error-page/), [2](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/aug/29/screencast-2-logging-fun-and-profit/), [3](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/aug/30/using-pdb-python-debugger-django-debugging-series-/) (which you linked to), and [4](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2008/sep/2/using-pdb-debug-management-commands-and-unit-tests/)

Comment: I made a summary nice for getting started in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71021836

Answer (score 17):

Synopsis:

```
# epdb1.py -- experiment with the Python debugger, pdb
import pdb
a = "aaa"
pdb.set_trace()
b = "bbb"
c = "ccc"
final = a + b + c
print final
```

Now run your script:

```
$ python epdb1.py
(Pdb) p a
'aaa'
(Pdb)
```

Comment: Or copy the code to `ipython` wrapping it in a function.