# How to retrieve values after a function crashes?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I retrieve a value from a function after it crashes? E.g. how would I find the value of `a` after the function completes/crashes.

```
>>> def a_is_3():
...     a=3
...     print 'a='+str(a)
... 
>>> a_is_3()
a=3
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

My real case includes massive numpy arrays created and passed around through dozens of modules. The arrays are still taking up memory after the code errors, but I can't access them.

Is there a way to retrieve what the variables were at the moment when the function crashed? I want to avoid having to add debug code and re-run the lengthy execution to capture the variables. It seems like a particularly useful trick for troubleshooting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228637/getting-started-with-the-python-debugger-pdb

Comment: you mean when a *function* crashes, not a *script*.

Comment: Are you asking how to make `a` a global variable, instead of local to the function? Or how to extract locals from the frame of a function call that already ended? Or… what?

Comment: I suppose what I ideally want is to recover locals from a function that has already ended, as I can still see them in memory.

Answer (score -1):

try to use `global`

```
>>> def a_is_3():
...     global a
...     a = 3
...     print('a=' + str(a))
...
>>> a_is_3()
a=3
>>> a
3
>>>
```

This will work quite well in an interactive session - but if you move this to a script later make sure you are aware of the implications.

Obviously, the variable `a` gets overridden in global scope, so be aware of that too.

Comment: just have to make sure there isn't an `a` already defined outside the function that is used for a different purpose.

Comment: Okay, that works fine for the simple case. But it doesn't work when I apply it to my real case, using a unique variable name. e.g. I insert into the code: `global ASDF; ASDF = X` and afterward get `NameError: name 'ASDF' is not defined`. X being a numpy array

Comment: @Trayder i don't think that error has anything to do with your case being more complicated.  i think it's because you haven't initialized `ASDF` outside the function (so there is an `ASDF` already defined to which the `global` call can refer).

Comment: @shadow "aware of the implications," which are . . . ?

Comment: `import __builtin__; __builtin__.ASDF = X` did it. global was insufficient because I needed to pass the variable across modules.

Comment: @dbliss if you were to copy multiple fragments of code together into a script that had global variables, they could clobber each other etc...

Comment: @shadow if you were to copy multiple fragments of code into an interactive session, wouldn't there be just as much clobbering?

Comment: That is one the implications of using global - yes...