# 'n' in pdb moves me inside of the pdb.set_trace() method

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, pdb

I'm trying to learn pdb using [this tutorial](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/) referenced from [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228637/getting-started-with-the-python-debugger-pdb), and I'm on the 3rd step of the Getting Started section.

```
In [12]: %paste
# epdb1.py -- experiment with the Python debugger, pdb
import pdb
a = "aaa"
pdb.set_trace()
b = "bbb"
c = "ccc"
final = a + b + c
print final
## -- End pasted text --
--Return--
> <ipython-input-12-48afa1c7ad72>(4)<module>()->None
-> pdb.set_trace()


(Pdb) l
  1     # epdb1.py -- experiment with the Python debugger, pdb
  2     import pdb
  3     a = "aaa"
  4  -> pdb.set_trace()
  5     b = "bbb"
  6     c = "ccc"
  7     final = a + b + c
  8     print final
[EOF]


(Pdb) n
> /Users/jg/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py(3038)run_code()
-> sys.excepthook = old_excepthook
(Pdb) l
3033                    self.hooks.pre_run_code_hook()
3034                    #rprint('Running code', repr(code_obj)) # dbg
3035                    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
3036                finally:
3037                    # Reset our crash handler in place
3038 ->                 sys.excepthook = old_excepthook
3039            except SystemExit as e:
3040                if result is not None:
3041                    result.error_in_exec = e
3042                self.showtraceback(exception_only=True)
3043                warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", level=1)
```

It looks like n(ext) should move me to the next line in the current frame:

```
(Pdb) help next
n(ext)
Continue execution until the next line in the current function
is reached or it returns.
```

And seems to do that successfully in the tutorial's example.  But in my ipython it appears to be moving me to the next line within the pdb.set_trace() code.

How do I simply navigate to the 'b = "bbb"' line?

Comment: An open github issue addresses this issue: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3930

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this in your ipython:

```
import pdb
def test_pdb_example():
    a = "aaa"
    pdb.set_trace() # use 'n' for navigate to next line
    b = "bbb"
    c = "ccc"
    final = a + b + c
    return final

test_pdb_example()
```

Comment: That works perfectly for me.  How can I get this work without wrapping it inside of a function, and what is the issue when it's not wrapped?

Comment: @user1956609 As far as I know, when you call pdb.set_trace(), it will try to execute sys._getframe().f_back(). If your code is not wrapped inside a function, sys._getframe().f_back() raises exception.

Comment: Is it a `bug` or a feature?