# Python debugging not working in python notebooks

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I've been utilizing jupyter notebooks for awhile and typically place an

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

in my notebook, which works as expected. Recently, I removed all Python related packages from my Windows machine and installed Enthought Canopy 32-bit. Now when trying to step through code via pdb I get the following

```
> <ipython-input-6-fdf950c00f74>(1)<module>()->None
-> import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) n
> c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\enthought\canopy32\user\lib\site-    packages\ipython\core\interactiveshell.py(2888)run_code()
-> sys.excepthook = old_excepthook
```

It seems to jump into interactiveshell.py and never gets back to the actual code I'm wanting to step through. I've noticed this also happens in the 64 bit distro of Enthought

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['n' in pdb moves me inside of the pdb.set\_trace() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529638/n-in-pdb-moves-me-inside-of-the-pdb-set-trace-method)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495269/debuggers-not-acting-properly-on-jupyter-notebooks