# Debuggers not acting properly on Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pdb

I'm trying to debug some code in a Jupyter notebook. I've tried <s>3</s> 4 different methods, and they all suffer from the same problem:

```
--Return--
None
> <ipython-input-22-04c6f5c205d1>(3)<module>()
      1 import IPython.core.debugger as dbg
      2 dber = dbg.Tracer()
----> 3 dber()
      4 tst = huh.plot(ret_params=True)
      5 type(tst)

ipdb> n
> y:\miniconda\lib\site-packages\ipython\core\interactiveshell.py(2884)run_code()
   2882             finally:
   2883                 # Reset our crash handler in place
-> 2884                 sys.excepthook = old_excepthook
   2885         except SystemExit as e:
   2886             if result is not None:
```

as you can see, the `n` command, which from what I understood from the `pdb` documentation should execute the next line (I'm assuming `ipdb` is just `pdb` adapted to work on IPython, especially since I can't find any command documentation that refers specifically to `ipdb` and not `pdb`)

`s` also has the same problem. This is actually what I want to do - step into the `plot` call (from what I understand, this is what `s` is supposed to do), but what I get is exactly the same as what I get from `n`. I also just tried `r` and I get the same problem.

Every example I've seen just uses `Tracer()()` or `IPython.core.debugger.PDB().set_trace()` to set a breakpoint in the line that follows the command, but both cause the same problems (and, I assume, are actually the exact same thing).

I also tried `%debug` (`MultipleInstanceError`) and `%%debug` (Doesn't show the code in the line being executed - just says what line, using `s` doesn't step into the function, just runs the line).

Edit: turns out, according to a blog post from April of this year, plain `pdb` should also work. It does allow me to interactively debug the notebook, but it only prints the current line being debugged (probably not a bug), and it has the same problem as IPython's `set_trace()` and `Tracer()()`

on plain `IPython` console, IPython's `set_trace` (only one I've tested) works just fine.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem when debugging in Jupyter Notebook. What is working for me however, is when I call set_trace() *inside a function*. Why is explained here [(click)](https://codexample.org/questions/499358/n-in-pdb-moves-me-inside-of-the-pdb-set_trace-method.c), though I don't really understand why others don't encounter this problem. Anyway, if you need a pragmatic solution for your problem and you want to debug a self-written function, try this:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace

def thisfunction(x):
    set_trace()        # start debugging when calling the function
    x += 2
    return x

thisfunction(5)        # ipdb console opens and I can use 'n'
```

[image]

Now I can use 'n' and the debugging process runs the next line without problems. If I use the following code, however, I run into your above mentioned problem.

```
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace

def thisfunction(x):
    x += 2
    return x

set_trace()            # start debugging before calling the function. 
                       # Calling 's' in the ipdb console to step inside "thisfunction" produces an error
thisfunction(5)
```

[image]

Hope this helps until somebody could solve the problem completely.