# Issue Debugging Jupyter Notebook Using ipdb & Tracer

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipdb

I have been running into issues when using the debugger within Jupyter Notebook,   Specifically this command:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import Tracer
Tracer()() #this one triggers the debugger
```

Whenever I use Tracer()() the inline debugger shows as expected, but once I enter any command in the field : n(ext), s(tep), etc. I jump to the line:

```
finally:
  # Reset our crash handler in place
  sys.excepthook = old_excepthook
```

Here is an image of the issue and the code that was attempted to be debugged (The exact code is not relevant as I am able to reproduce the issue in other notebooks).

[image: Jupyter Notebook Tracer()() Output]

I am working on a mac running OSX El Capitan, and using Anaconda for python 2.7. Here are some details about my current setup obtained by running:

```
conda info --all (from root env)
```

[image: System Information via: conda info --all from (root) env]

Note, I have tried several different debugging options: pdb, ipdb, and Tracer() but ran into separate issues with each. Tracer() seems like the standard option at this time, per the Stackoverflow question [Using ipdb to Debug Python Code in Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613249/using-ipdb-to-debug-python-code-in-one-cell-jupyter-or-ipython).

Additionally, I have been able to replicate this issue on my Dell computer running Windows 7.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've the exact same problem, have you solved this issue yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['n' in pdb moves me inside of the pdb.set\_trace() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529638/n-in-pdb-moves-me-inside-of-the-pdb-set-trace-method)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495269/debuggers-not-acting-properly-on-jupyter-notebooks