# Is there a python 3.x debugger like gdb

Tags: python, debugging

I am wondering if there is a python debugger as powerful as gdb, for example at setting breakpoints, stepping into functions, and the like. I have been working with gdb in c and assembly and it has been excellent. SO is there a python debugger like so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pdb might be what you are looking for.

There are many resources for how to use it. See this post for some resources: [Getting started with the Python Debugger pdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228637/getting-started-with-the-python-debugger-pdb).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was awesome