# Inserting data into a database using forms in web2py

Tags: forms, web2py

I want to store my data in a database using forms.

How can I do it without using `SQLFORM` 
like in `php` we use `$var = $_POST['var_form']`

I created a table in modul file called Produit

```
db.define_table('Produit',`enter code here`
           Field('Nom', requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
           Field('Poid', 'float', requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
           Field('Prix', 'float', requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
           Field('Expiration', 'datetime'),
           auth.signature)
```

And created a form like

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
```

`<form action="create" method=post>`

```
<fieldset>
<legend><h1><center><em>Ajouter un produit</em></center></h1></legend>
Nom:<br>
<input type="text" name="nom" required/>
<br>
Poid:<br>
<input type="text" name="poid" required/>
<br>
 Prix:<br>
<input type="text" name="prix" required/>
<br>
Date d'expiration:<br>
<input type="date" name="exp" required/>
<br>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Ajouter">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `URL` helper to specify action of the form.

```
<form action="{{=URL('create')}}" method=post>
...
</form>
```

Then in `create` controller, you can access submitted values using `request.vars`

```
db.Produit.insert(Nom=request.vars.nom, Poid=request.vars.poid,
                  Prix=request.vars.prix, Expiration=request.vars.exp)
```

Comment: Thank you 
But i have another problem
When i insert a product on database "Produit" i found it but i found another product with values 'None'.

Comment: @AmineSghiouriEl-idrissi that means your controller that contains `insert` statement is called twice. Did you refreshed view of that controller or directly opened view of above controller. Add [pdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228637/getting-started-with-the-python-debugger-pdb) and check.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39061092/440323) has the right idea, but to make things a little easier, you should use HTML field names that exactly match the database table field names. In that case, you can simplify the insert to:

```
db.Produit.insert(**db.Produit._filter_fields(request.post_vars))
```

Beware, though, that your manual approach lacks any protection against CSRF attacks (which the web2py form system would provide). As an alternative, note that you can still use `SQLFORM` even if you want to generate a custom form layout in the view. This approach is covered in the documentation [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM-in-HTML) and [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Custom-forms).