# Any disadvantage using Terminal as opposed to the deprecated GoogleAppEngineLauncher?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, command-line

I'm doing [Udacity's Web Development course](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/cs253).  I've heard some users talk about Eclipse, but I'd rather have a basic understanding of the command line than move on to that higher level software.

Is there anything on a Mac that I can't do in Terminal that I could on Google App Engine Launcher?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't get stuff working with mouse clicks. But I suspect you might not actually miss that :) Under the GUI MacOS is quite similar to Linux and the Linux GAE SDK is entirely CLI-based. So I'd expect the same functionality to be available in the Mac SDK as well.

Answer (score 0):

The gcloud commands from the Cloud SDK provide much more control over your experience. The App Engine Launcher actually causes more problems than it helps with. In the long run, you're much better off with gcloud.

If you wanted to use an IDE, there are new plugins for [Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/) and [IntelliJ](https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/). If you wanted to keep debugging simple, you could just use the command-line [PDB debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4228643/1354939).