# How to refer to entries inside nested python dictionaries? unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

This is something I'm extending from a Code Academy exercise. My wife's a teacher, so it's something I very well might want to apply eventually. The original exercise created dictionaries for three students, with their name and grades in each dictionary under 4 sub entries, name, homework, quizzes, tests. It occurred to me that in extension, new separate dictionaries for each student might get messy, and it might be better to create a parent dictionary (for each class?) that students could then be added to. I haven't been able to get it to work, but when I change it around, the errors seem to come in different places, typically `unhashable type: 'list'`

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong, how to refer correctly to the nested data?

```
classdict = {
  'lloyd': {
      "name": "Lloyd",
      "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
      "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
      "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
      },
  'alice': {
      "name": "Alice",
      "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
      "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
      "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
      },
  'tyler': {
      "name": "Tyler",
      "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
      "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
      "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
      },
  }

def average(numbers): #average generator
    total=sum(numbers)
    total=float(total)
    total =total/len(numbers)
    return total

def get_average(student): #gen a weighted average from different grade types
    homework = average(classdict[student["homework"]])
    quizzes = average(classdict[student["quizzes"]])
    tests = average(classdict[student["tests"]])
    return float(0.1*homework + 0.3*quizzes + 0.6*tests)

def get_letter_grade(score): #this generates a letter grade from an average
    if score>=90:
        return "A"
    elif score>=80:
        return "B"
    elif score>=70:
        return "C"
    elif score>=60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"


#this is a function to call an individual student's grade        
pupil = raw_input("Which student?").lower()

if pupil in classdict.keys():
    print get_letter_grade(get_average(
  classdict
  [pupil]))
else:
  print "Unknown student."

#this is intended to calculate the class average  
students = list(classdict.keys())
def get_class_average(student):
    results = []
    for student in classdict:
        results.append(get_average(classdict[student]))
    class_average = average(results)
    return class_average

print get_class_average(classdict[students])
print get_letter_grade(get_class_averag(classdict[students]))
```

My typical input//error would be

```
Which student? Alice
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 55, in <module>
  File "python", line 31, in get_average
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

NB I understand there may be a much better way to arrange my database. Suggestions would be helpful, but I'm really looking to understand where my syntax is off in this particular arrangement, as I'm trying to learn as well as get a solution.

NB2 I did look at a couple of answers to similar questions, but they seemed to be addressing different issues (eg retrieving value, rather than in a function).

NB3 Fixed missing close brackets eg `results.append(get_average(classdict[student]))`

Comment: You included everything except *what is wrong with the code you have*. Please include a [mcve], including a full stacktrace if you're getting an exception.

Comment: classdict[student]["homework"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there were 3 issues primarily:

1. missing closing `)` at few places
2. The method to access a dictionary key value should be `dict[key]` and if the dictionary is nested then it should be `dict[key1][key2]` and not `dict[key1[key2]]`
3. `get_average()` expects just the student name (i.e. string). But at few places `classdict[student]` (which is a dictionary) was being passed to it.

Try this:

```
classdict = {
  'lloyd': {
      "name": "Lloyd",
      "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
      "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
      "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
      },
  'alice': {
      "name": "Alice",
      "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
      "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
      "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
      },
  'tyler': {
      "name": "Tyler",
      "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
      "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
      "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
      },
  }


def average(numbers): #average generator
    total=sum(numbers)
    total=float(total)
    total =total/len(numbers)
    return total


def get_average(student): #generates a weighted average from different grade types
    homework = average(classdict[student]["homework"])
    quizzes = average(classdict[student]["quizzes"])
    tests = average(classdict[student]["tests"])
    return float(0.1*homework + 0.3*quizzes + 0.6*tests)

def get_letter_grade(score): #this is to generate a letter grade from an average
    if score>=90:
        return "A"
    elif score>=80:
        return "B"
    elif score>=70:
        return "C"
    elif score>=60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"


#this is a function to call an individual student's grade        
pupil = raw_input("Which student?").lower()

if pupil in classdict.keys():
    print get_letter_grade(get_average(pupil))
else:
  print "Unknown student."

#this is intended to calculate the class average  
students = list(classdict.keys())
def get_class_average(student):
    results = []
    for student in classdict:
        results.append(get_average(student))
    class_average = average(results)
    return class_average

print get_class_average(students)
print get_letter_grade(get_class_average(students))
```

Comment: Code only answers are rarely helpful, as they don't help the OP or future readers understand *why* they were incorrect.

Comment: @TemporalWolf, Probably you didn't notice that the keys to the `classdict` are lowercase.

Comment: You're correct. This answer still needs an explanation to be helpful to future readers.

Comment: The .lower() was because that function was referring to the dictionary for each student, which was in lowercase (since I personally would usually type with a capital). The "name" stored inside each student's dictionary could easily be a full name, nickname etc. 

Thankyou for picking up the closing brackets. It's now saying a different error I hadn't been getting before: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 55, in <module>
  File "python", line 31, in get_average
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" - so now've a new thing to google.

Comment: @toonarmycaptain, are you sure, you have copied all the code from my answer. There were few other errors fixed as well related to accessing dictionary elements elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry, did not copy and paste, was trying to spot differences and correct, rather than drag and drop - I want to see where the errors are, what they are, and understand why, as I tried to explain in my request. It does work now, but why do you sometimes have to use parentdict[][""] and sometimes just call the variable, or another_function(variable)?

Comment: Might I suggest, as your question really boils down to *how to refer correctly to the nested data?* that you only need the classdict declaration and only 1 line of code accesssing it that is throwing an error?  The smaller your sample code on SO, the better your chance at good answers.

Comment: @toonarmycaptain, Not sure if I understand what you asked but let me try. `parentdict[][""]` is required when you want to access values from the nested dictionary. The variable can be passed to a function and within the function you may again use it to access the values in the dictionary in the same way.

Comment: yeniv yes, I think that's what I was asking. Cheers :)
@JLPeyret thanks for the advice. I did think about trimming it down, but I thought I'd not be able to explain what I was trying to do as clearly as if I simply put the code on there. Next time I might try breaking it into two questions, though.

Comment: by the way, is there a clear "why" for the parent[][""] method of reference, rather than parent[key["key"]] or is that just "the way it is"?

Comment: If you use `parent[abcd["def"]]` that means that you want to access the parent dictionary one level only and the key that you want to use is `abc["def"]` which is itself fetched by accessing a value from another dictionary named abc by looking up a key def. On the other hand, `parent[abc]` means accessing the value of key abc in dictionary abc and `parent[abc]["def"]` means accessing the key "def" in the value of key abc in dictionary parent i.e. two level down the parent dictionary. Also note that I am saying `abc` and `"def"` assuming that `abc` is a variable while `"def"` is string literal.

Comment: To further add, you may actually need to use `dict1[dict2["key"]]` at times. But here, `dict1` and `dict2` are separate dictionaries. `dict2["key"]` gives you another key which is further used to index into `dict1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
homework = classdict[student]["homework"]
```

A shorter form of

```
studentdict = classdict[student]
homework = studentdict["homework"]
```

Comment: So the way to refer to the lower nested items is with [] around each subsequent level of nesting, with quotation marks around the last one (the one you'd be calling)?

Comment: The quotes are just because homework is a hardcoded key in your code. student however is variabke hence no quotes. The succceeding [] are kinda like dot notation. classdict.a.b.c would classdict["a"]["b"]["c"].

Comment: Btw, any missing key in the chain will get you a KeyError exception.

Comment: Thankyou. So in my example, classdict["alice"]["quizzes"] is correct, classdict["alice"]["quizzes"][n] is correct, classdict["alice"]["quizzes"]["2"],  would be correct, but not classdict["alice"]["quizzes"][2] because the third item in the list could be changed?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the 3rd item in list.  But it's a list (almost, but not quite, an array like in other languages) so 2 is an index position (needs to be an integer), not a key. It's not a dictionary access.  If you struggle, break nested accesses down into bits, like I did in the 2 lines of my example.

Comment: You could use the debugger to llok at your code "live". See. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228637/getting-started-with-the-python-debugger-pdb

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so since what's wrong with your current code is well covered, I would recommend going about this a different way by using classes and objects. See the working example on [repl.it](https://repl.it/Hf0I/1):

```
def avg(lst):
    return sum(lst)/len(lst)

class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.homework = []
        self.quizzes = []
        self.tests = []
    #generates a weighted average from different grade types
    def get_average(self): 
        homework = avg(self.homework)
        quizzes = avg(self.quizzes)
        tests = avg(self.tests)
        return 0.1*homework + 0.3*quizzes + 0.6*tests

    #this is to generate a letter grade from an average
    def get_letter_grade(self): 
        score = self.get_average()
        if score>=90:
            return "A"
        elif score>=80:
            return "B"
        elif score>=70:
            return "C"
        elif score>=60:
            return "D"
        else:
            return "F"

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, students):
        self.students = students

    def get_average(self):
        return avg([student.get_average() for student in self.students])

lloyd = Student("Lloyd")
lloyd.homework = [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0]
lloyd.quizzes = [88.0, 40.0, 94.0]
lloyd.tests = [75.0, 90.0]

alice = Student("Alice")
alice.homework = [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0]
alice.quizzes = [82.0, 83.0, 91.0]
alice.tests = [89.0, 97.0]


tyler = Student("Tyler")
tyler.homework = [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0]
tyler.quizzes = [0.0, 75.0, 78.0]
tyler.tests = [100.0, 100.0]

my_class = MyClass([lloyd, alice, tyler])

print my_class
print my_class.students

for student in my_class.students:
    print student.name

print my_class.get_average()

for student in sorted(my_class.students, key=lambda x: x.get_letter_grade()):
    print "%s: %s(%6.2f)" % (student.name, student.get_letter_grade(), student.get_average())

pupil = raw_input("Which student?" ).title()  # Forces capitalization to: Xxxxx

for student in my_class.students:
    if student.name == pupil:
        print student.name, student.get_letter_grade()
```

So instead of using dictionaries, we are using objects of our own design. The benefit to this is **we** get to decide what you can do to them and what they store. So I say that you can `get_letter_grade()` on a `student`. Now all students will act in this way. The biggest difference is you won't be referring to students by an object name. I could have named my students `dummy1`, `dummy2`, and `dummy3`, just as easily. It's better to sort on a property, like the `name` field.

Comment: Cheers :) this does look much cleaner and flexible. I've seen classes referenced, but not gotten to them in the exercises I'm working through. This is day 4 I think since I started looking at Python, so I've a ways to go! dummy_n is definitely something I'd love to hide in each students' element if I ever do code something for my wife to use ;)

Comment: @toonarmycaptain In real code you wouldn't name them. just make a class and then append new students in without assigning the object a name: `my_class.students.append(Student("Tracy"))` for example.